# Before using Expo eject, I would like to know if my packages like react-navigation or react-native-datetimepicker will continue to work

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I've been working on an Expo project and I want to kick it out but wonder if react-navigation and react-native-datetimepicker will still work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I presume "kick it out" is an attempt to translate "éjecter", but it's not the right phrase. Possibly you mean "release", but I'm not sure why that would make part of your code stop working. You'll need to provide more details of what you're doing and what you need help with.